# How to access a case class' parameter from context of a trait

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, case, traits

I have a trait, say:

```
sealed trait foo
```

And a case class that extends trait:

```
case class bar(data: List[String]) extends foo
```

I would like to write a function that accesses bar's data, but it is passed as foo, say:

```
def doSomething(x: foo) = {does something with foo.data}
```

And called like this:

```
val aBar = bar(some list)
doSomething(aBar)
```

But I can't access when the function doSomething expects a type foo. How can I get around this to access a bar type's values?

Comment: If you ask for a **Foo** then you can only use want a **Foo** provides, that is basic principle of polymorphism. You may declare `data` in **Foo** or do pattern matching if the trait is sealed. Or maybe ask for a **Bar** instead,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this makes sense in the context of your program, but you could define `Foo` as follows:

```
trait Foo {
  def data: List[String]
}
```

If that doesn't make sense, then perhaps you should pattern match:

```
def doSomething(x: Foo) =
  x match {
    case bar: Bar => ...    // or `case Bar(data)`, as Luis suggests
```

Note that I have capitalized `Foo` and `Bar` everywhere; class and trait names should always be capitalized in Scala code, at least if you want anyone else (for example, people helping you on Stack Overflow) to be able to read the code without getting confused.

Comment: `case Bar(data)` ;)

Comment: Oops, I have my naming conventions sorted in my code but absent mindedly typed all this. Thanks for the reply. I should've been more clear that I would like doSomething to be as generic as possible, in that Bar may contain a list of something other than Strings. I used case matching and it worked perfectly. Still learning the details of Scala and forget some of the tools at my disposal.